# How to fix "A RenderFlex overflowed by 40 pixels on the right." in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm creating a simple user form, but I got a problem with ' A RenderFlex overflowed by 4o pixels on the right. How do I fix this render problem?

I tried to fix it with `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,` by putting the line of code under the TextFormField but I got error with the unrecognizable of the `overflow` words inside my code.

[image]

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context){
  final halfMediaWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.0;
    return Form(
    key: _formKey,
     autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
      child: Column(  
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  width: halfMediaWidth,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                    decoration : InputDecoration(labelText: "No"),
                    inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  width: halfMediaWidth,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      decoration : InputDecoration(labelText: "ID"),
                    ),
                  ),

                ),

              ],
            ),
          ),
         
        ],
      ),
    
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some remarks:

1. There's no reason for using `halfMediaWidth`, you can just use `Expanded`.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Form(
      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
      child: Column(  
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration : InputDecoration(labelText: "No"),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration : InputDecoration(labelText: "ID"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

2. There's no reason for using alignment inside a `Row`, you're already using `CrossAxisAlignment.start`.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Form(
      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
      child: Column(  
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration : InputDecoration(labelText: "No"),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration : InputDecoration(labelText: "ID"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

3. That being said, there's no reason for using a `Container`.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Form(
      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
      child: Column(  
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      decoration : InputDecoration(labelText: "No"),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      decoration : InputDecoration(labelText: "ID"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

4. There's no reason for using alignment inside a `Column`, you can use the `crossAxisAlignment`.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Form(
      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
      child: Column(  
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      decoration : InputDecoration(labelText: "No"),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      decoration : InputDecoration(labelText: "ID"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

5. There's no reason for using a `Container` wrapped in `Row`.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Form(
      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
      child: Column(  
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    decoration : InputDecoration(labelText: "No"),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    decoration : InputDecoration(labelText: "ID"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Using the refactored code, see if it's still giving you the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  final halfMediaWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.0;
    return Form(
    key: _formKey,
     autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
      child: Column(  
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  width: halfMediaWidth,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                    decoration : InputDecoration(labelText: "No"),
                    inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  width: halfMediaWidth,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      decoration : InputDecoration(labelText: "ID"),
                    ),
                  ),

                ),

              ],
            ),
          ),
         
        ],
      ),
    
    );
}
flutterflutter-layout
```

Comment: Hi, would you mind adding some explanation why the already posted answer did not work for you and why your approach is better?

Comment: You should add explanation.